# Matlab question: Converting a permutation matrix into a vector showing row exchanges

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

Let me preface that I am an absolute beginner with Matlab. I am trying to perform $PA=LU$ factorization on a matrix, however I am having difficulty with the permutation matrix. When I execute $[L,U,P]=lu(A)$, I want to be able to represent the permutation matrix as a one-dimensional array of integers recording which row interchanges have been made.

For example, if $P=[0 1 0 ; 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1]$, then I am looking to find how I can achieve an output of $p= [2 1 3]$.

I figure that there was an easy way to execute this result. I simply do not have the experience to figure it out on my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Compute $P \cdot \left(\begin{array}  &1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ \end{array} \right)$, and then transpose to get it in rowvector shape.

Comment: I see what you did there if the permutation is a 3x3 matrix. But what if a matrix is NxN in size?

Comment: The same basic principle holds except you should multiply it with the vector $\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \\ \dots \\ N \end{array} \right)$.

Comment: How do you do the opposite in Matlab (convert a permutation vector into a matrix)?  See my question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379809/is-there-a-name-for-this-function-parity-of-a-finite-sequence .